# Is there any python script for .des file creation?

Tags: python, sprite

I have some images of .png extension how can i generate .des extension files of them can anybody help me in  that

Comment: update your question to talk about image formats, not file "extensions".

Answer (score 0):

The [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) suite which has [python bindings](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/pythonmagickwand) supports over a 100 file [formats](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php).

The `.des` extension is used by a lot of different programs. Please specify what you mean exactly.

Comment: I want a script that takes a bunch of images and combines them into one sprite file and creates the .des files that point to the location of each graphic in the sprite file

Comment: A DES file is very tiny plain text file. In this file you can find information about the atlas file including: where to find atlas (resource) image AND describe the position of original image on atlas image.

Basically, this DES file tells us where certain images are in the big ATLAS image. As example if you have a folder called MainMenu and two files button.png and levelIcon.png after atlas making process you’ll have two DES files button.des and levelIcon.des and two big images MainMenu.png and MainMenu_hi.png ( *_hi.png is for Retina Displays and IPad )